# Save LinkedList to Parse Server

Tags: objective-c, linked-list, parse-server

I'm trying to build a **Single Linked List** using Parse PFObjects. Each PFObject has a pointer to the **next** object in the list. I can pin them locally, but I'm having an issue when saving them to Parse Server.

The problem start here:

```
+ (BFTask *)_deepSaveAsyncChildrenOfObject:(id)object withCurrentUser:(PFUser *)currentUser sessionToken:(NSString *)sessionToken;
    // This saves all of the objects and files reachable from the given object.
    // It does its work in multiple waves, saving as many as possible in each wave.
    // If there's ever an error, it just gives up, sets error, and returns NO;
```

When trying to save the first object in the list, it will access the child (next object) and try to save that one first. As the child (next object) has also a pointer to the next object in list, this will keep happening until the last object in the list.

This succeeds for small amount of objects (<200) but once we are handling linked list with **large amounts of objects**, there is a **crash** in here:

```
/**
 Finds all of the objects that are reachable from child, including child itself,
 and adds them to the given mutable array.  It traverses arrays and json objects.
 @param node  An kind object to search for children.
 @param dirtyChildren  The array to collect the result into.
 @param seen  The set of all objects that have already been seen.
 @param seenNew  The set of new objects that have already been seen since the
 last existing object.
 */
+ (BOOL)collectDirtyChildren:(id)node
                    children:(NSMutableSet *)dirtyChildren
                       files:(NSMutableSet *)dirtyFiles
                        seen:(NSSet *)seen
                     seenNew:(NSSet *)seenNew
                 currentUser:(PFUser *)currentUser
                       error:(NSError * __autoreleasing *)error
```

This method is called by `deepSaveAsyncChildrenOfObject` to build a NSSet of the children objects that must be saved too.

```
@synchronized ([object lock]) {
            // Check for cycles of new objects.  Any such cycle means it will be
            // impossible to save this collection of objects, so throw an exception.
            if (object.objectId) {
                seenNew = [NSSet set];
            } else {
                if ([seenNew containsObject:object] && error) {
                    *error = [PFErrorUtilities errorWithCode:kPFErrorInvalidPointer
                                                     message:@"Found a circular dependency when saving."];
                    return NO;
                }
// CRASH: Thread 160: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x70000fc80f38)
                seenNew = [seenNew setByAddingObject:object];
            }

            // Check for cycles of any object.  If this occurs, then there's no
            // problem, but we shouldn't recurse any deeper, because it would be
            // an infinite recursion.
            if ([seen containsObject:object]) {
                return YES;
            }
            seen = [seen setByAddingObject:object];

            // Recurse into this object's children looking for dirty children.
            // We only need to look at the child object's current estimated data,
            // because that's the only data that might need to be saved now.
            toSearch = [object._estimatedData.dictionaryRepresentation copy];
        }
```

So, this could be avoided by saving the PFObjects **without saving its children**, is there any way to do this? Or is there any **workaround** to save linked lists to Parse Server, maybe by using Cloud Code, or modifying the data model?

Comment: Why you want linked list here we can do it through array isn't it ?

Comment: Arrays have their downsides: 1. When removing an object, we have to find all references to it from each array, which could be costly. We've also had database corruptions in the past because a pointer in an array was pointing to a removed object. 2. When reordering objects, the whole array has to be saved again.
3. When syncing two libraries, we had planned to support merging as opposed to overwriting position changes of objects within a parent. This is not possible with an array, because you'd have to replace the entire array with the newer, reordered version.